# Drupal 6 - Site information broken after duplicating site. DB hacks needed?

Tags: php, drupal-6

I have a drupal site which I deved a few years ago.  We duplicated it to a new site/domain/db (which pulls from a subdirectory of the original site)

I tried to only duplicate the site settings (views and content types), and leave out all the site node data (it is a content driven site, and we are launching a sister site).  Everything wen OK.  Unfortunately, in the new site, I find that I cannot update "site information" (which means I cannot set my front page). I tried to update the data in the DB, but that let to the relevant site settings field to appear blank

I i had to implement a ridiculous hack to deal with the fact that the front page is now technically a 404.  Even more weirdly, the original site has the same problem now (all I can guess is that I updated the table from the wrong DB by mistake?!? ).

As best I can tell, this data is stored in "variable" in the DB.  I have imported a good "variaable" table from an old copy of the site, but to no avail.

So I am completely stuck.  If anybody has any leads whatsoever, I would be incredible grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Kind of vague what you're asking for here.  From what I can see, you're wanting to duplicate the design and structure of the site, but not the data, is that correct?  Have you tried using the DOMAIN module?

Comment: @webdevsoup We already duplicated it through thoroughly manual means.     We wanted to move the structure, but not the content (which we did) it's just that site settings (only, as far as I can tell) seems to have gotten corrupted somehow. --- I'm looking at domain now, but at the moment we want seperate installs (is that bad for some reason?  drupal seems so fragile to me, I hate to add more dependencies to it)

Comment: can you post the link to the site?  settings.php could be corrupted, and I have also had issues with .htaccess being missing as well.  These 2 files could be your issue.  Thats the reason I'm not posting an answer, it could be many things going on.  Check with the .htaccess file first.  That's my initial impression.  After that, settings.php could be the issue.

Comment: I think your problem is not the content of you database (because that would be fixed from your import auf the "good dump").

Reasons could be changes in the sql server software/settings (e.g. transfer encoding of the connection) of in the php version/settings (you have to ask your webmaster).

It also could be something with the files (e.g. to less permissions to your drupal files). 

Do you get any error or watchdog messages in your drupal with details of this error?